# Enable query string issue in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to enable query string in codeigniter 3.1.2 but after changing all setting i am not able to enable it pls help me

my config.php setting

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
$config['enable_query_strings'] =TRUE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger'] = 'd';
```

and after this i am getting my url like

```
http://127.0.0.1/new/?computer
```

i don't know where i am wrong pls help me guys
and also my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Try with this `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';`

Comment: Then in the url `http://localhost/project/index.php?c=welcome` this should go to the welcome controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also check the configuration between Apache and PHP. You may need to tinker with php.ini and apache2.conf/httpd.conf (depends on which distro you are). But as a quick test you should be able to see **mod_rewrite** being loaded.

```
<?php
print_r(apache_get_modules());
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-get-modules.php